# ArrayFormula - If cell contains match, combine other cells with TEXTJOIN

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a Google Sheet that contains names of characters, together with corresponding values for the group name, "selected" and attack power. It looks like this:

**Sheet1**

```
| NAME     | GROUP NAME | SELECTED  | ATTACK POWER |
|:---------|:-----------|----------:|-------------:|
| guile    | Team Red   |         1 |          333 | 
|----------|------------|-----------|--------------|
| blanka   | Team Red   |         1 |           50 |
|----------|------------|-----------|--------------|
| sagat    | Team Red   |           |          500 |
|----------|------------|-----------|--------------|
| ruy      | Team Blue  |         1 |          450 |
|----------|------------|-----------|--------------|
| vega     | Team Blue  |         2 |          150 |
```

**Sheet2**

In my second sheet, I have two columns. Group name, which contains names of each team from Sheet1 and names, which contains my current ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1; 
 REPT('Sheet1'!A:A; 1*('Sheet1'!B:B=A2))))
```

Using this formula I can combine all characters into one cell (with textjoin, repeated with row breaks) based on the value in Group name. The result looks like the following:

```
| GROUP NAME | NAME                      |
|:-----------|:--------------------------|
| Team Red   | guile                     |         
|            | blanka                    |
|            | sagat                     |
|------------|---------------------------|
| Team Blue  | ruy                       |
|            | vega                      |
|------------|---------------------------|
```

The problem is that I only want to combine the characters with having a selected value of `1`. End-result should instead look like this:

```
| GROUP NAME | NAME                      |
|:-----------|:--------------------------|
| Team Red   | guile                     |         
|            | blanka                    |
|------------|---------------------------|
| Team Blue  | ruy                       |
|------------|---------------------------|
```

I tried the following setup using a IF-statement, but it just returns a string of FALSE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1; 
 REPT(IF('Sheet1'!C:C="1";'Sheet1'!A:A); 1*('Sheet1'!B:B=A2))))
```

Can this be one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **F2** cell:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, C:C=1))
```

paste in **G2** cell and drag down:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, FILTER(A:A, B:B=F2, C:C=1))
```

[image: 0]

---

or **G2** cell be like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, 
 REPT(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!C:C=1), 1*(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!C:C=1)=F2))))
```

[image]

Comment: You are my hero. Amazing, just as I described.

Comment: @player0 Am I correct in understanding that your second G2 formula example above, acts exactly like the first G2 formula?  Ie. it is not filling down the column as is normal for an arrayformula, but just going through the REPT process using the arrayformula?  If so, is there any way to have a single formula in column G that does fill down that column?  (Only two instances in this case, but if there were many...)  Many thanks for any feedback.

Comment: @kirkg13 yes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/149Z2bRDcS8a3JCv5OgSBZzVU2hOwyQSk4gGb9IsBFfw/edit#gid=0